# What determines the amount of loot that can be stolen from you?

Tags: age-of-empires-castle-siege

When you are attacked by an enemy, what factors contribute to how much loot can be taken from you? Is it simply uncollected resources from your farms, mills, quarries, and so on, or is there another factor that can be controlled?